# TypeError: Cannot read property 'actualPersonAlbum' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am dealing like a 3 days ago with this mistake when I try to know the state in redux in a class component react, the problem is when I try to know the state "actualPersonAlbum" here is my code [image about the mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yCV9.png)

```
React class WorkSection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const {relations} = this.props.relations;
    console.log(relations); 
    const {actualPersonAlbum} = this.props.actualPersonAlbum;  //The probleeeeeem 
    console.log(actualPersonAlbum);
    return (
       <section style={ sectionStyle }>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

WorkSection.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  relations: state.relations,
  actualPersonAlbum: state.actualPersonAlbum,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (withStyles(workStyle)(withRouter(WorkSection)));
```

Redux reducer

```
import { GET_RELATIONS, 
  SET_ACTUAL_ALBUM_PERSON } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    actualPersonAlbum: "",
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ACTUAL_ALBUM_PERSON:
        return{
    actualPersonAlbum:action.payload,

        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Redux action

```
import {GET_RELATIONS,
    SET_ACTUAL_ALBUM_PERSON
} from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const setActualAlbumPerson = actualPersonAlbum => {
    return {
      type: SET_ACTUAL_ALBUM_PERSON,
      payload: actualPersonAlbum
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to do, is destructuring `actualPersonAlbum`.

If you would like to have it worked, the data props should look like:

```
{ 
    actualPersonAlbum: {
        actualPersonAlbum: ...,
    },
}
```

Didn't you just want to destructure it only **once**?

```
const { actualPersonAlbum } = this.props
```

However if you really want to destructure that property twice, just secure the possibility that `actualPersonAlbum` is not defined yet (because it comes from async request or so).

```
const { actualPersonAlbum } = this.props.actualPersonAlbum || {};
```

Comment: I did the last thing and still undefined, I know that this is really the mistake, but I dont know why is undefined if I see everything fine in the reducer and in the action.

Comment: Thank you for answered me I didnt know that this is called destructuring :)

Comment: @NATHALIACEBALLOSHURTADO Please show me the result of `console.lo(state)` inside `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: relations: {relations: Array(5), actualPersonAlbum: "Mamá Alicia"} that is the result. So, it seems like a the redux part is ok in the state but the destructuring is bad

Comment: @NATHALIACEBALLOSHURTADO Just console.log it in render `console.log(this.props.actualPersonAlbum)`

Comment: still undefined

Comment: I did this.props.relations.actualPersonAlbum and it works but I dont understand why hahha, cause I have this in all the reducer
https://ibb.co/CHNZLFX